# Linux - Track Files on SFTP server

Tags: linux

I have a SFTP server, when the file are upload to the SFTP server, the info are written to /var/log/

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
    Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -l INFO
```

This works great.  the code above tells which file has been upload and to which directory but if I was to move that file to a different location, nothing is written to the system logs.

Let say file ab.txt was upload to, /global/info/temp/**ab.txt** 
moves to /blah/blah/**ab.txt** 
finally moves to /user/inbox/**ab.txt**

The problem is that there are over 100 files that are being upload to the SFTP server to various directories and their filenames are different as well.  In the example above, file ab.txt which was upload to the "temp" directory, was then moved to the "blah" and finally to the "inbox" directory?

Is it possible to track file, "ab.txt"?

Thanks

Comment: `INFO` -> `VERBOSE`. Is it enough?

Comment: I tried INFO -> VERBOSE or DEBUG  
also tried LogLevel VERBOSE or DEBUG or DEBUG2 or DEBUG3  
Nothing worked.

Comment: OK. In what way was it not enough?

Comment: @Kamil I'm sorry but I don't understand the question.

Comment: In my tests `VERBOSE` caused the server to log events of [moving files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92963/108618). I can imagine few reasons this log may be not enough for you. What is the reason then? Did you see these events in the log in the first place? Did you reload the SSH server after changing the configuration?

Comment: So this is what I have,  
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -l VERBOSE  
then I restarted ssh,  
systemctl restart sshd.service  
  
I tried to move the file,  
mv /global/temp/AB.txt /data/test/  
The move was NEVER written to the system logs,

Comment: I'm using red hat.  Can you tell me the command you use to move the file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138411/discussion-between-user1736786-and-kamil-maciorowski).